# The equation of a straight line on semi - logarithmic scale passing through two points

Tags: pine-script, logarithm

what I want is the equation of a straight line on a semi - logarithmic scale passing through two points. I will use it in an indicator.
The base equation is as follows:

```
y = k * 10 ^ mx
m = slope of line = ∆(log y) / ∆x
k = y-intercept: value of y where line crosses the x = 0 axis
```

for example:

```
x0 = 69
x1 = 174
y0 = 0.0000296
y1 = 0.0001652
m = (log10(y1) - log10(y0)) / (x1 - x0)
k = y0 / pow(10, m * x0)
y = k * pow(10, m * bar_index)
plot(y)
```

While this equation is absolutely correct, the result of plotting it on logarithmic scale was a curve:
https://www.tradingview.com/x/5Tl0lDK0/

**Then I realized that apparently in the price < 0.001 range, the logarithmic chart of Tradingview is not working logarithmically!**

See this image: https://www.tradingview.com/i/3vWZsxND/

I am so confused.

**Does anyone know the cause?**

**What is the equation corresponding to the chart scale?**

Please help if you can.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Concerning the scale with small values, it's expected behavior. Some charts on TradingView can go into negative territory. This would not be possible to accomplish on a real log scale, which is why the actual scale is only logarithmic up to a point and then it changes to linear. It's a necessary compromise to accommodate edge cases such as charts with negative values, drawings with coordinates that go below 0, etc.

[EDIT 2021.06.07 10:08 — LucF]

The equation for the calculation is as follows:

```
//@version=4
study("My Script", overlay=true)
x1 = bar_index[10]
y1 = input(0)
x2 = bar_index
y2 = input(1000)
xi = bar_index[4]
isLog = input(true)
LOGICAL_OFFSET = 4
COORD_OFFSET = 0.0001
f_toLog(_price) =>
    _m = abs(_price)
    _res = log10(_m + COORD_OFFSET) + LOGICAL_OFFSET
    _m < 1e-8 ? 0 : _price < 0 ? - _res : _res
f_fromLog(_logical) =>
    _m = abs(_logical)
    _res = pow(10, _m - LOGICAL_OFFSET) - COORD_OFFSET
    _m < 1e-8 ? 0 : _logical < 0 ? - _res : _res
f_lineGetPrice(_x1, _y1, _x2, _y2, _xi) =>
    _y1 + (_y2 - _y1) / (_x2 - _x1) * (_xi - _x1)
f_lineGetPriceLog(_x1, _y1, _x2, _y2, _xi) =>
    _y1Log = f_toLog(_y1)
    _y2Log = f_toLog(_y2)
    _target = f_lineGetPrice(_x1, _y1Log, _x2, _y2Log, _xi)
    f_fromLog(_target)
if barstate.islast
    l1 = line.new(x1, y1, x2, y2)
    labelHeightxiBarsBack = isLog ? f_lineGetPriceLog(x1, y1, x2, y2, xi) : f_lineGetPrice(x1, y1, x2, y2, xi)
    label.new(xi, labelHeightxiBarsBack, text = tostring(labelHeightxiBarsBack))
```

Comment: Thank you for your complete and correct answer and wonderful support

Comment: It worked well before, but now something seems to have changed. 
I made the following changes and the result was much better:
LOGICAL_OFFSET = 10,  COORD_OFFSET = 0. 
Can you help me again?
Thank you in advance 

Comment: The answer still seems to work correctly here. Do you have example code and chart showing unexpected behavior?

Answer (score 0):

You can approximate the desired curve by using the following snippet.

```
x0 = 69
x1 = 174
y0 = 0.0000296
y1 = 0.0001652
m = (log(y1) - log(y0)) / (log(x1) - log(x0))
y = y1* pow(bar_index/x1, m)
plot(y)
```

Although this does not provide an exact match, the curves are quite close to each other and you might utilize this form for your calculations.

Comment: @TH-990 I modified the solution to address the new modifications of your question.

Comment: Thank you.
But I need the line equation to use in an indicator.
I added more details, please read.

Comment: @TH-990 I have modified the answer and you can use the described technique to obtain the values of the line and utilize in your indicator. Note that you have made serious changes to the question which change the original meaning of the question and it would be better if you asked those questions in a new thread and I would be happy to answer them. I hope this method was helpful.

Comment: Thanks, but the "line.get_price" command returns the Y value of the line on a linear scale even if the chart is set to logarithmic scale mode.
Do you think I should delete the question and publish it again?

Comment: @TH-990 I see the problem with line.get_price. I came up with this curve on log-scale(not semi-log) that seems to approximate your desired curve better. Although it still has problems like inability to achieve negative values. I hope you can build up a better results by using this. There is no need to delete the question, but I would edit this new parts of the question and compile them into a separate thread.